# uwp app (.net native) and unhandled exception

Tags: c#, uwp, unhandled-exception, hockeyapp, .net-native

I created uwp app(.Net native) for Windows 10 desktop. I use [HockeyApp](http://hockeyapp.net) for collect live crash reports. Stack trace not informative. This is a long-standing problem and it does not have a solution. I tried [this](https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-windows-and-windows-phone/how-to-upload-symbols-for-uwp-application) but it not working.
I get these exceptions:

```
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
Arg_NullReferenceException

Microsoft.HockeyApp.Extensibility.Windows.UnhandledExceptionTelemetryModule.CoreApplication_UnhandledErrorDetected
 The parameter is incorrect. The parameter is incorrect.
```

On my computer the application works stably. Perhaps this is due to the versions of Windows. also I think that this is due to my xaml. It is very important for me to correct these mistakes. But I can not refuse the table. 
Any ideas how can I find the source of these errors?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Sorry, this may not be an answer but I don't have enough room in the comments box.*

---

Try the following in your `App.xaml.cs`. Add a handler to these events and see if they report something back to you about crashes.

```
public App()
{
    UnhandledException += OnUnhandledException;
    TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += OnUnobservedException;

    InitializeComponent();
}

private static void OnUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    // Occurs when an exception is not handled on the UI thread.


    // if you want to suppress and handle it manually, 
    // otherwise app shuts down.
    e.Handled = true; 
}

private static void OnUnobservedException(object sender, UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    // Occurs when an exception is not handled on a background thread.
    // ie. A task is fired and forgotten Task.Run(() => {...})


    // suppress and handle it manually.
    e.SetObserved();
}
```

Comment: `e.Handled = true;` has no bearing on the program terminating for me. Any idea what could be the cause for this?